# Add a css filter to the background of a sticky navbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a  transparent or opaque sticky navbar and add some css filter like blur to its background. I ended up making two overlapping navbars with the same dimension. One with the text and the other one with the filter (They are both transparent or opaque) so the filter won't be applied to the text but only to the background  but it seems like the filter isn't working. Here's the code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

nav {
    height: 56px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.menu {
    flex: 1;
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.menu>p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

nav p:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.background {
    height: 63px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="menu">
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="background">
    </div>
    <main>
        <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-yvHXo7HtHDE/UATxfDGF1BI/AAAAAAAAFFM/hFE4J9QtiYQ/s1600/Landscape.jpg">
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try backdrop-filter to achieve this effect.**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 1200px;
}

nav {
  height: 56px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu {
  flex: 1;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.menu > p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

nav p:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
main {
  margin-top: -66px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="menu">
        <p>Example</p>
        <p>Example</p>
        <p>Example</p>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <img
        src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-yvHXo7HtHDE/UATxfDGF1BI/AAAAAAAAFFM/hFE4J9QtiYQ/s1600/Landscape.jpg"
      />
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set this blur filter for the "nav" element's ::before CSS code as follow:

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
}

nav {
 height: 56px;
 padding: 5px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: baseline;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 2;
    
}

nav::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(8px);
  z-index: 3;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.38);
}

.menu {
 flex: 1;
 width: 40%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.menu > p {
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
}

nav p:hover {
 cursor: pointer; 
}

.background {
 height: 63px;
 width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav>
   <div class="menu">
    <p>Example</p>
    <p>Example</p>
    <p>Example</p>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="background">
  </div>
  <main>
   <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-yvHXo7HtHDE/UATxfDGF1BI/AAAAAAAAFFM/hFE4J9QtiYQ/s1600/Landscape.jpg">
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```